# Validating Database after migration

Tags: mysql, migration, data-migration

We have 5000+ Dbs (on MySQL - Unix Machine) each having similar 30-40 tables. We are performing Migration activity from one machine to another (again same on MySQL - Unix Machine).

Once the migration is completed, how can a tester confirm if the activity was successful or not?

What we tried is:

SELECT table_name AS "Table", round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) "Size in MB" FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = "<\Schema Name>";

It provides us details about one DB, but we have 5000+ DB to compare. which would be tedious task. Or else we would have to opt for Sampling but that is not a concrete solution.

Any helpful suggestions are welcomed!!

Thank You in advance!

-- Chirag Fisher

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mysqldbcompare`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/mysqldbcompare.html) to check databases both at a high level and row-by-row. It's part of MySQL Workbench, or available as a separate download.

If you want to bake your own, you can use [`innochecksum`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innochecksum.html), a built-in MySQL tool for reading InnoDB data files that gives you a per-table checksum, allowing you to ensure the data in each table is identical across instances.

You could similarly use the [`CHECKSUM TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/checksum-table.html) MySQL command to do the same thing, perhaps as part of your database import scripts.